# Java Batch Execution - OpCon Scheduling tool

Tags: java, xml, batch-processing, job-scheduling

Need help for resolving below junk characters issue..

Ran the batch from putty -> It reads data from Oracle db tables and converts data into XML -> Working as expected.

Ran same batch using OPCON Scheduler getting junk characters in XML for Portuguese text.

Expected Result : Não reúne as condições

Junk text created from batch in XML : N?o re?ne as condi??es

Comment: Possibly an encoding issue.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps that we’ve performed to prevent the Junk characters in XML generating from the Opcon Enterprise Manager.

1. Stopped the LSAM Services from the Linux and Machine Communication
   from Enterprise Manager.
2. We’ve enabled the SU access in the LSAM Config file. Lsam Configuration Parameters

   ```
         Enter path_to_su  [no] : yes
   ```
3. Restarted the LSAM Services from the Linux and Machine communication
   from the Enterprise Manager